# What are proper uses of "get into"?

Tags: meaning, usage

I've just run across [this definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+into) in The Free Dictionary:

> get into — *Informal* To be interested in: got into gourmet cooking.

And it doesn't really sound right to me. Isn't "get" about changes? Like when I didn't like cooking before and now I like. That is, isn't it rather "to become interested in"? Then, it can't possibly be used in Present Simple, because the latter is about what you usually do. So Present Perfect and maybe Past Simple are probably better fits.

So, to sum it up, does it really mean "to be interested in" and not "to become interested in"? Could you provide some examples in different tenses with some context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, i think you are right about the use of it - in the above meaning it can't be used in the present tense.

'Get into' means that you have started doing something

examples

1. When did you get into drinking ? - (When did you start drinking)
2. When did she get into ballet ? - (When did she start doing ballet)
3. He has gotten into learning English. (He's started learning English)

None of the above examples can be used in the present tense. - So that was a perfect point.

Comment: Yes, I think both the OP and this answer are correct.  It is possible to use this sense of *get into* in the present simple in a habitual sense, though: "Yeah, she really **gets into** books about vampires.  It doesn't matter how poorly they're written!"

Answer (score 1):

"Get into" can also be used to indicate an intended future action.
"I have decided that next year I am going to get into yoga."
"After watching some videos, I decided I did not want to get into yoga."